# Useragent redirect if 404

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

At the moment if a 404 page is requested by a useragent it returns "**Unable to get URl**"

What I'm looking for is a script (probably best done in php or **.htaccess**) that will redirect to a certain page if called from a certain useragent if it's a 404 page.
I think it could also be done with a status type thing as if it's a 404 page it returns Status 404 in the visitor log.
At the moment I use this to simply redirect if it's the useragent.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WinInet
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /pagehere.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: seems like that world work? so are you saying it dosent?

Comment: This would work if the index was called but what I'm looking for is if any page is called that's a 404 page it redirects to pagehere.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess add this code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/website/redirect_404.php 
#(Your 404 error redirect file location)
#ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/redirect_404.html (To redirect to a url)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/redirect_404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/website/redirect_404.php [L]
#The ErrorDocument redirects all 404s to a specific URL
```

Inn your redirect_404.php file enter this code

```
<?php
   header('Location: /errorfolder/404/'); //Path to your error file
   exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule for non-files and non-directories (similar to 404):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WinInet
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /pagehere.html [L]
```